# Force compilation with qt4 even if qt5 is installed

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt4, cmake

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and have both qt4 and qt5 installed (from the repositories). I thought I could switch between building with qt5 to building with qt4 simply with

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-default
```

But the program still builds with Qt5 and gives error because it only supports Qt4.

I checked the qmake version and after qt4-default is installed it gives

```
$ qmake --version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I'm building with CMake in case that is useful. Also, if I do

```
sudo apt-get remove qtbase5-dev
```

then finally it builds with qt4.

EDIT: I am not using Qt Creator and would prefer a command-line solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to put this into your CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
... 
include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(main ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: If you already have this as well as Qt 5 cmake code, you could establish a cmake -DQT4 define to handle all this distinction.

Comment: I did not realize that I had to do it at the CMake level. I thought there was some system way to hide qt 5, but I guess that would not be a recommended way..

Comment: @XuWang: I am not aware of any, but let me know if there is any. Cmake has new way of doing things for Qt 5, rightfully.